# LACP doesn't work on FreeBSD VM without promiscuous mode

Tags: freebsd, virtualbox, lacp

I'm running two identical FreeBSD 12.1-RELEASE VMs on VirtualBox. Each VM has 2 network interfaces, `em0` and `em1`, set to `Internal network` mode. `em0` interfaces are set to `intnet0` network and `em1` are to `intnet1`.

I have configured LAGG on both machines in the following way:

```
ifconfig_em0="up"
ifconfig_em1="up"
cloned_interfaces="lagg0"
ifconfig_lagg0="laggproto lacp laggport em0 laggport em1 192.168.33.x/24"
```

`x` equals `1` for the first VM and `2` for the second one.

After booting, I get nice `ifconfig` output on both machines:

```
lagg0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING...
    inet ...
    laggproto lacp lagghash l2,l3,l4
    laggport: em0 flags=1c<ACTIVE,COLLECTING,DISTRIBUTING>
    laggport: em1 flags=1c<ACTIVE,COLLECTING,DISTRIBUTING>
    status: active
```

However, pings simply do not pass.

Now if I go into VM's settings and enable promiscuous mode for both adapters and both machines, it starts to work.

Does LACP require setting adapters into promiscuous mode? Or maybe I'm facing a bug in VirtualBox/FreeBSD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of a question of the hypervisor. The VM is only passing packets into the VM if they have the VM's MAC address on it, so you will need to enable promiscuous mode in order to use LACP in ANY operating system.

Comment: I still don't quite get it. Can you elaborate, please? You mean, that even on real hardware I'd need to put adapters into promiscuous mode? Handbook doesn't mention that.

Comment: No. In this case, it is basically a 'virtual switch' that is part of the hypervisor. By default it is filtering packets that go into the VM. If you don't enable this mis-named feature in the hypervisor, then the LACP packets never make it into the VM.